# included css & js in html for node http server is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below are my code but not working, I am including CSS & JS in proper way in html but still it's not including also check below screenshot.

Node Js Code :

```
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    var pg = require('pg');
    var path = require ('path');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    /* Database connectivity */
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
       host: "localhost",
       user: "root",
       password: "",
       database: "training.com"
    });

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

    app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
       res.sendfile('user-profile-edit.html');
    });

    app.post('/', function(req, res){
       console.log('req.body');
       console.log(req.body);
       var nme= req.body.name;
       var eml= req.body.email;
       var drs= " Sucessfully Inserted ";
    });

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('My Current port:8080');
```

ScreenShot :http://prntscr.com/fds2ee

Comment: Can you also show your html file?

Comment: Sure Please check  :         

       ` <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link href="assets/libraries/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link href="assets/libraries/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <link href="assets/libraries/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`               

Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/fdsekl

Answer (score 0):

Give the static folder a relative path like `/assets`:

```
   app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
```

In you `html`

```
<link href="/assets/libraries/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css‌" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: I'm glad it works! Please mark my answer if you are happy with the fix